# mySQL - UPDATE TRIGGER, how to compare a .NEW value to another piece of data in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

What I've been trying to do is have a trigger statement fire before a value of a row is updated.

The statement will need to see if the new deposited amount to be updated is larger than an existing debt that is in another column, this is what I have tried so far.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER BankTrail 
BEFORE UPDATE ON loan
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF (NEW.`paid`> OLD.debt) THEN
    INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (.....);
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The table (Loan) structure is 3 columns

**DEBT PAID CUSTNO**

I if the amount PAID is Greater than the DEBT I need the trigger to work.

I've tried using OLD.DEBT (but this is no use as the debt amount is not being changed during the update)

I've also considered using a SELECT statement as in

```
IF (NEW.`paid`> SELECT 
debt 
FROM loan
WHERE ...?
) THEN
```

But again, there is no identifier to then select the row, by using CUSTNO or DEBT as none of those are changed in the initial UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE loan
 SET paid = (amount paid)
 WHERE custno = (customer number);
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **BEFORE UPDATE** to **AFTER UPDATE** and your trigger should work